# Looking for one or two Node modules related to locking and update scheduling

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Some people are going to think this is too trivial to look for modules or almost put it in a leftPad category perhaps, but there are so many things in npm I have a feeling these two requirements are covered and so am interested to see what other people have done.
I inherited this codebase that has this sort of long updating function with a number of steps. It has sort of a custom locking flag that is half-set up to expire but doesn't actually have the expiration code. Anyway the main thing is to prevent the update from happening while something else is happening. Except sometimes we know we definitely need to update as soon as possible, but not right in the middle of a current update. This stuff is not actually quite working.
So I am looking for one or two modules to do two things:

1. a lock with an expiration that two different long-running functions (that call other functions with callbacks) can use to make sure they don't step on eachother
2. a simple module/function that says 'do this function now, or run it again after it finishes its current run'.

Or possibly something that handles both of those might actually make sense in this case, even though from my description it may not be obvious what they have to do with eachother.

The expiration is if there is some case that I don't anticipate that causes the lock not to be removed for a very long time, we don't want to be stuck forever.

Here is an example:

```
function update() {
  // if we are trading, wait until that is done
  // if currently updating, skip it or schedule another one right
  // after, but only need one more, not a queue of updates
  // make a bunch of callbacks or a promise chain, takes a few seconds
  // in some cases we will find that we need to do one more update
  // immediately after all of this finishes, but not until the end
}

// ...some other places that want to call update

function trade() {
  // trade happens sort of sporadically when the tick event fires
  // if we are updating, wait until we are done
  // make a bunch of callbacks or a promise chain, takes a few seconds
  // at the end we need to call update
  // but it can't  update if it is already updating
}
```

Comment: Did you check lodash [`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) and [`_.throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle)? These sound about what you're trying to do, although it's really hard to tell with just very abstract descriptions.

Comment: Maybe the expiration thing is confusing it a little.  throttle might sort of handle #2 except it really just needs to call the update again after it finishes, not after a timeout.  Maybe ignore the expiration thing if its not clear because it was really secondary.

Comment: You can set the timeout to 0 or call the function again at the end. If you don't want to risk stack overflow error, and don't want to use one of lodash functions, you can wrap the call in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` or promise so the VM will create a new task or microtask. Note that microtasks (created with properly implemented promises, e.g. inside V8 - Chrome, node) are much faster (~100x) than setTimeout approach.

Comment: OK thanks I think _throttle will handle #2, I will test it.

Comment: should a pending update execute after all queued trades, or after any trade? The answer I submitted will run and clear the pending update after any trade completes.

Comment: It will need to update after every trade.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, I made a few updates, but I think it works. A more elegant/generic solution would probably be cleaner. I'm really curious if there isn't an npm package that hits exactly this use case. I don't think _.debounce and _.throttle hit it on the head precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thank you so much for your help guys.

This is what I decided I need to do: I created a really simple module [now-or-again](https://www.npmjs.com/package/now-or-again) and am using the existing [lock-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lock-lock) with its maxPending feature instead of an expiration time.

The way I am using those two modules is identical to the examples in the READMEs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
// note using a bluebird type of promise
const tradeQueue = [];
var currentlyTrading = false;
var currentlyUpdating = false;
var pendingUpdate = null;
var queuedUpdatePromiseDetails = null;
// returns a promise that returns void, the promise will return
// when either the currently executing update finishes, or a fresh one
// does
function update() {
  var test = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  console.log(test, 'update call');
  if (!pendingUpdate) {
    pendingUpdate = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      queuedUpdatePromiseDetails = { resolve: resolve, reject: reject, test: test };
      if (currentlyTrading) {
        console.log(test, 'setting update to pending');
      } else {
        // perform update, in callback call resolve() if no err, otherwise reject(err)
        console.log(test, 'running update');
        currentlyUpdating = true;
        setTimeout(resolve, 100);
      }
    }).finally(function () {
      currentlyUpdating = false;
      console.log(test, 'update call complete');
      pendingUpdate = null;
      queuedUpdatePromiseDetails = null;
      runPendingTradeOrUpdate();
    });
  } else {
    console.log(test, 'returning existing update promise', queuedUpdatePromiseDetails.test);
  }
  return pendingUpdate;
}

// returns a promise that completes when this
// new trade finishes
function trade(param) {
  var test = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  console.log(test, 'trade call');
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (currentlyTrading || currentlyUpdating) {
      console.log(test, 'queued trade')
      var newTrade = { param: param, resolve: resolve, reject: reject, test: test };
      tradeQueue.push(newTrade);
    } else {
      currentlyTrading = true;
      console.log(test, 'beginning trade run');
      // perform trade, in callback call resolve() if no error, otherwise reject(err)
      setTimeout(resolve, 100);
    }
  }).finally(function () {
    console.log(test, 'trade call complete');
    // note that this bit is run for every single trade
    currentlyTrading = false;
    runPendingTradeOrUpdate();
  });
}

// dequeue next trade and run it
function runPendingTradeOrUpdate() {
  if (queuedUpdatePromiseDetails && !currentlyUpdating && !currentlyTrading) {
    // perform update, in callback call resolve() if no err, otherwise reject(err)
    console.log(queuedUpdatePromiseDetails.test, 'running pending update');
    currentlyUpdating = true;
    setTimeout(queuedUpdatePromiseDetails.resolve, 100);
  } else {
    if (tradeQueue.length > 0 && !currentlyTrading) {
      var nextTrade = tradeQueue.shift();
      console.log(nextTrade.test, 'calling queued trade');
      trade(nextTrade.param).then(nextTrade.resolve).catch(nextTrade.reject);
    }
  }
}


var runRandomly = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    update();
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300))
  setTimeout(function () {
    trade(null);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300))
  setTimeout(function () {
    runRandomly();
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300))
}

runRandomly();
```

Comment: Also, if a trade has higher priority, use .unshift to put it at the front of the queue, or consider a priority queue.